# How do I make the form resort to a certain part of the code?

Tags: html, forms, action

I am making something for new shadowing students (and I get extra credit) and I have encountered an error. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Icebreaker</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<form class="#" action="#" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>


<!--- Insert action code here --->

</body>
</html>
```

How do I make the `action` resort to a certain part of the html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action in a form is going to redirect you to another url that is going to process the form submission. So, if the action in the form would be something like:

```
<form method="post" action="/show_icebreaker">
   @csrf
     .
     .
     .            
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then, you would have a *Route* like this: `Route::post('/show_icebreaker', '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@show_icebreaker');`

In the *HomeController* as in my example, you should have something like:

```
public function show_add_edit_ps(Request $request){
    $FirstName = $request->fname;
    .
    .

    //You can return a view  
    return view('show_icebreaker_view')->with(['FirstName' => $FirstName]);

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, but can you elaborate on it?

Comment: @James First, in your html file which is your form add method and action as shown. Thus, method="post" and action="/show_icebreaker".
Secondly, you have to create a new Route in your web.php file as explained in the answer.
Third step, would be to add in your Controllers, let's say your HomeController the function to manipulate the input of your form request. (fname, lname).
Finally, you can create a new html file called 'show-icebreaker_view'. From your Controller you can pass data to your view by using the with() method.

Comment: Okay! thats awesome!!